# PHP add constant on load before scripts

Tags: php, startup

I was wondering if it possible to add constants to php before any scripts are ran, thus on startup. If this is possible, could it be done with classes etc aswell?

I was thinking in the direction of creating a plugin for php but maybe there is a way simpler way.

I don't mean including a file in every script.

thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you use `define` http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Could you try explaining your problem in more detail, instead of asking about the implementation details of a potential solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer the question, there are two approaches:

1. Use `auto_prepend_file` to auto include a PHP file that has `define` calls.
2. Configure your web server to set server variables.

I think the second is a better approach. However, I don't see how either of them are very useful in the context of a plugin. Usually a class autoloader of some sort is the way to go there, or to require a single include file.

Comment: lol Mathew, saw 14.4k under your name and for a second I thought that was what you were dialing in to the internets with .. flash back to '96

Answer (score 3):

Not constants as far as I'm aware, but this is ok:

**.htaccess**

```
SetEnv MYVAR "hello"
```

**somefile.php**

```
echo $_SERVER['MYVAR'];
```

See the [Apache docs on SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) for more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what I do is to `include` a file before all else on my `index.php`. That same file contains tons of `constants`, `control verifications`, `initialization for the DB object`, etc...

e.g.,

**INSIDE index.php**

```
<?php

$moduleRoot = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once($moduleRoot."/components/inc/inc.php");

// continue to render the web page and perform as usual

?>
```

**INSIDE THE inc.php**

```
// When in development, all errors should be presented
// Comment this two lines when in production
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Website id for this project
// the website must be present in the table site in order to get
// the configurations and records that belong to this website
define("CONF_SITE_ID",1);

// Domain path where the project is located
// Should be like the access used on the browser
$serverDomain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$serverAccess = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? ('https://') : ('http://');
$serverRoot = dirname(__FILE__);
define("CONF_DOMAIN", $serverAccess.$serverDomain);

// etc ...
```

---

### EDITED

Since you have multiple "startup" files and you need all of them to call `inc.php`, the best choise seems to be `.user.ini` as of PHP 5.3.0, you can read about [it here!](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php).

And an [article](http://www.untwistedvortex.com/php-configuration-files-reusable-code/) on the subject.

Comment: This solution fails as soon as there are separate files which need the inc.php to include the inc.php therefore the info has to be know beforehand

Comment: @John, added an edit to the answer with a solution for that issue! Also a link to an article on the subject.